# Windows 10 firewall allows apps “is already in the list of exceptions”

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

On Windows 10 I've installed an app which needs access to the internet.

Windows does not ask for a firewall exception like it usually does when I first run an app.

When I go to the firewall's "Allow apps" window and try to add it manually, Windows says the app "is already in the list of exceptions." The app is not in the list.

How do I add this app to the Windows 10 list of allowed apps?

Comment: Try to disable all security software and firewall temporarily, just ti check, then return it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ways:

Before we define program exceptions in “Windows Firewall”, make sure that the “Windows Firewall: Allow local program exceptions” setting is enabled in Group Policies:

Click “Start”, click “Run”, type “gpedit.msc”, and then “OK”

Under “Local Computer Policy” expand “Computer Configuration” > “Administrative Templates” > “Network” > “Network Connections” > “Windows Defender Firewall”, and then click “Domain Profile”

Right-click “Windows Firewall: Allow local program exceptions”, and then click “Properties” or simply double-click it.

Click “Enabled”, and then “OK”

We can also use the “Windows Defender Firewall: Define program exceptions” setting to configure local program exceptions.

We can also type the following command in command prompt to add a program to the Windows Firewall Exception list.

For details we can refer to the link: https://www.network-inventory-advisor.com/help/faq9/

Comment: This answer appears to come from an article on handling firewall exceptions for Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Windows apparently set things right. The next time the app was run, Windows 10 asked for permission for internet access as expected.